# Find the largest-sum sub-matrix

Tags: java

**1.** I have a 2D array, representing a matrix. I need to find a **square** sub-matrix that has the biggest summation. The size of the sub-matrix is number of rows or columns divided by 2. For example, if I have this

```
9 3 5 9
2 5 9 8
8 4 9 7
9 5 3 9
```

the biggest  sub matrix is going to be

```
9 8
9 7
```

because it has the  biggest summation.

---

**2.** Second, I need to find the biggest sub-matrix with permutations. By that I mean, I need to choose the biggest numbers with the shape of a sub-matrix (at least two number in the same column or same row). For example the four nines in the diagonal edges

```
9 9
9 9
```

but I cannot take the first row and make a matrix because it does have the shape of the matrix.

I am still struggling with that so Please help me.

Here is my code and subm is the size of the submatrix

```
for (i=0;i<rows-subm;i++){
          for(j=0;j<colums-subm;j++)
          {
             temp=pic[i][j]+pic[i][j+1]+pic[i+1][j]+pic[i+1][j+1];
             if(temp > summax)
                 summax=temp;
          }
 }
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Talk it out with a stuffed animal for a bit.  What do you know?  What do you need to approach the problem?  Above all, what code do you have that will guarantee that you find the largest values for a sub-matrix?  I would think that 9 8 9 7 would be the largest sub-matrix.

Comment: For part#1, you need to look for all possible sub-matrices. You may choose to d a recursion or look for Dynamic Programming. This is standard problem.

Comment: BTW, put some negative quantities in your example... if the matrix is always all positive you just need to consider biggest square sub-matrices only. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the matrix determinant computation approach. Check out this [example](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/Determinant_of_matrix_in_java). The Determinant of a 2x2 matrix will be computed as

a b

c d

```
ad-cb

Instead use a+b+c+d
```

replace 2x2 matrix computation in the example with

```
result = mat[0][0] + mat[1][1] + mat[0][1] + mat[1][0];
```

record all these values and find the maximum from them

Comment: Thanks everybody. I am greately appreciate it.